# How to center content col-xs-4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have HTML block:

```
<div class="class-journal-mobile-navigation">
<div class="col-xs-4"><div class="block"></div></div>
<div class="col-xs-4"><div class="block"></div></div>
<div class="col-xs-4"><div class="block"></div></div>
</div>
```

How to center div block `.block` inside parent `.col-xs-4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS:

```css
.col-xs-4{
  text-align: center;
}

.block{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="class-journal-mobile-navigation">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="block">A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="block">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="block">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to align the contents of the div .block, you can use this

```
.block {
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What version of Bootstrap are you using? Might need to amend but this assumes version 4 for now.

Bootstrap grids should have parent `row` class.

```
<div class="row class-journal-mobile-navigation">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For quick CSS it may better to make it more specific to `.class-journal-mobile-navigation` that you have defined and as a child of `.col-xs-4`.

```
.class-journal-mobile-navigation .col-xs-4 {
  text-align: center;
}
.class-journal-mobile-navigation .col-xs-4 .block {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

There are many useful CSS classes that you could make use of here. To help define the layout specifically for the XS breakpoint and not need additional CSS. Here's an example of how some of those classes might apply to your example.

```
<div class="row class-journal-mobile-navigation">
  <div class="col-xs-4 text-center text-sm-left">
    <div class="d-inline-block d-sm-block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 text-center text-sm-left">
    <div class="d-inline-block d-sm-block"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 text-center text-sm-left">
    <div class="d-inline-block d-sm-block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Flex classes are yet another option!

```
<div class="col-xs-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add `text-center` to the col class? Or you can try to add to the row class the `justify-content-center` class.